# prove that this function has Lebesgue measurable image

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Denote by $\lambda$ the standard Lebesgue measure.

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(E)<\infty$.

By an **initial segment** of $E$ we mean a set $E'\subseteq E$ satisfying $E'<E\setminus E'$ (in the sense that $x<y$ for all $x\in E'$ and $y\in E\setminus E'$).  Note that initial segments of $E$ must always have the form $E\cap(-\infty,y)$ or $E\cap(-\infty,y]$ for some $y\in[-\infty,\infty]$.

It can be shown that for each $t\in[0,\lambda(E)]$, there exists an initial segment $E_t$ of $E$ with $\lambda(E_t)=t$.

Let us define the function $m:E\to[0,\lambda(E)]$ by the rule
$$m(x)=\inf\{t\in[0,\lambda(E)]:x\in E_t\}.$$

**Conjecture 1.**  The image $m(E)$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set.

**Discussion.**

**(i)**  Clearly, $m$ is **order-preserving** (i.e., nondecreasing) in the sense that $x\leq y$ if and only if $m(x)\leq m(y)$.

**(ii)**  It can be shown that $m$ is **measure-preserving** in the following sense:  If $A\subseteq[0,\lambda(E)]$ is Lebesgue-measurable then $m^{-1}(A)$ is also Lebesgue-measurable with $\lambda(A)=\lambda[m^{-1}(A)]$.

**(iii)**  If $F\subseteq E$ and $m(F)$ is measurable then $\lambda[m(F)]=\lambda(F)$.

**(iv)**   There are definite counter-examples showing that $m$ need not be surjective. In fact, $[0,\lambda(E)]\setminus m(E)$ may even be uncountable.

Sorry to keep asking so many similar questions.  I keep running into these technical, seemingly obvious facts which are resistant to a simple proof (that I can find, anyway).

Comment: It seems from that definition that $E$ and $\emptyset$ are initial segments of $E$, but they are not necessarily of the form $E\cap(-\infty,y)$ or $E\cap(-\infty,y]$ for some $y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: How is $E_t$ defined if $E$ has more than one initial segment of measure $t$?

Comment: @bof  Oops!  I meant for $y\in[-\infty,\infty]$.  Fixed.  As for $E_t$, it is not necessarily unique.  But its existence is secured by applying the intermediate value theorem to the function $f:[-\infty,\infty]\to[0,\lambda(E)]$ defined by the rule $f(s)=\lambda\{x\in E:x\leq s\}$.

Comment: I don't understand $E'\subseteq E$ satisfying $E'<E\setminus E'$.

Comment: @zhw I added a definition in the OP. It just means $x<y$ for all $x\in E'$ and $y\in E\setminus E'$.

Comment: Seeing as $E_t$ is not unique, what does the condition $x\in E_t$ mean in the definition of $m(x)$?

Comment: @bof It means we fix some $E_t$ for each $t\in[0,\lambda(E)]$.

Comment: We can prove that, for any $x \in E$, $m(x) = \lambda((-\infty,x] \cap E))$. **Proof:** 
For any $x \in E$ and any initial segment $E_t$ such that $x \in E_t$, we have that $(-\infty,x] \cap E \subseteq E_t$. Since $(-\infty,x] \cap E$ is an initial segment, it follows that $m(x) = \lambda((-\infty,x] \cap E))$.

Comment: Good observation!  That may help prove the conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove that, for any $x \in E$, $m(x) = \lambda((-\infty,x] \cap E))$. **Proof:** 
For any $x \in E$ and any initial segment $E_t$ such that $x \in E_t$, we have that $(-\infty,x] \cap E \subseteq E_t$. Since $(-\infty,x] \cap E$ is an initial segment, it follows that $m(x) = \lambda((-\infty,x] \cap E))$.

Now, define for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $M(x) =  \lambda((-\infty,x] \cap E))$. It is clear that $M$ extends $m$ and that $M(E)=m(E)$. So we must prove that $M(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Note that, given any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, suppose without loss of generality that $y\geqslant x$, so we have:
$$ |M(y)-M(x)| = M(y)-M(x) = \lambda((x,y] \cap E))\leqslant y-x=|y-x|$$

So $M$ is a Lipschitz function. So the image by $M$ of any Lebesgue measurable set is Lebesgue measurable. So $M(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**In more detail:** 
Since Lebesgue measure is inner regular, there exist a set $N$ of measure zero and a sequence of compact sets $\{K_n\}_{n\ge 1}$, such that 
$$E=N\cup(\cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n)$$ Since Lebesgue measure is outer regular and $M$ is a Lipschitz function, $M(N)$ has measure zero. Since $M$ is continuous, $M(K_n)$ is compact for every $n\ge 1$. Therefore,
$$M(E)=M(N)\cup\big(\cup_{n=1}^\infty M(K_n)\big)$$ 
is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: It says I can't award the bounty for another 10 hours. Also, I would like to credit you in the paper I am writing. Do you have a full name?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll let you know when I get it on the arxiv.